# Leave unollocated space in case of increasing partition size in the future?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, swap

I plan to partition my disk into EFI partition, `/`, `/home` and swap

I also want to prepare when I might need to increase `/`  `/home` or swap in the future.

1. So shall I  scatter unallocated space between `/` and `/home`, and
   between `/home` and swap?

   or not leave any unallocated space, but relying on shrinking some partition to free space in the future?

   or arrange the unallocated space together between two partitions, rather than scattering them several places between the partitions?
2. If I leave some unallocated space between `/` and `/home`, will I be
   able to add some space from the unallocated space to `/home`? Note  that it
   will change the beginning of `/home`, and I wonder if that will
   change some meta information stored at the beginning of `/home` partition (is that bad?)

   I assume that I can add some space from the unallocated space between `/`  and `/home` to `/`, because that will added to the end of `/`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, Just keep it at the end of the disk to optimize performance as long as you don't need the unallocated space.  Once you need it, just do the necessary steps before you go to bed (moving partitions takes a long time) and let the computer work all night.
2. Yes. It just means that `gparted` will do an extend and move behind the scenes for you.
   `

Comment: Thanks. I always fear to try moving and resizing partitions, for  messing up my files and partitions. Can you point me to some readings about how i can do that in both GUI (gparted) and CLI (parted) ways?

Comment: http://gparted.org/documentation.php and http://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/